# Rails Internationalization translate a word and append to a model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

My translation works great, but when I try to append a field of my model I get and error:

This is the code:

```
<%=t :beneficios @offer.benefits %>
```

this is the error:

```
app/views/offers/show.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')'
...er.append=(t :beneficios @offer.benefits );@output_buffer.sa...
```

The problem is when I try to append the model field. But I can't find a solution on google and I don't think this is an option:

```
<%=t :beneficios %><%= @offer.benefits %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

Comment: I already check the guide and I can't an example like my

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a coma after :beneficios :)

```
<%= t :beneficios, @offer.benefits %>
```

Comment: Oh I'm surprised, `unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')'` is typical of a syntax error. Now you added a coma what's the error message?